# create a task to run after a time period in app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, time, task-queue

I need to run 2 tasks around 2 minutes apart but need to insert them both at the same time into the queue. how do i do this?

```
taskqueue.add('/task1', { 'args' : 'a' })

taskqueue.add('/task2', { 'args' : 'b' })
```

is there some way i can insert a time component into this execution?

can you please illustrate with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/tasks.html) for the Task class and read about the `countdown` and `eta` args on the constructor.  I think either one will allow you to do what you want.